# How to define a complicated hyphenation for Chinese pinyin

Tags: hyphenation, automation

I am setting a document with Chinese pinyin. I use `\-` to separate syllables in pinyin phrases (eg. `zhong\-wen`). This not only allows for proper hyphenation, but also allows spell check in Emacs/AUCtex.  A problem occurs with the hyphen for such words as Chang'an or Xi'an.  Entering these words as `Chang'\-an` or `Xi'\-an` would retain the apostrophe even if hyphenated at the end of the line.  Is there a way to make the apostrophe drop if the word is hyphenated, but kept otherwise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\-` is defined via the `\discretionary` primitive, so you should be able to go

```
Xi\discretionary{-}{}{'}an
```

where the arguments are the text to use before a break, after a break, or if no break.